# Are there any rules regarding the usage of a medical condition in movies?

Tags: legal, ghajini

In some movies, sometimes medical conditions are shown inaccurately. For example, in [Ghajini (2008 film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghajini_(2008_film)), [anterograde amnesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anterograde_amnesia) is shown wrongly. The main protagonist has anterograde amnesia, but he sometimes doesn't even remember his past, which is medically inaccurate.

So, are there any rules regarding the usage of medical terms/conditions/diseases in an inaccurate manner?

Comment: From what I've seen, no, there are no rules regarding how one can represent medical conditions in movies.  But I can't give a definitive answer, hence a comment.

Comment: The problem is that a lot of people take movies as "word of God" in that they will believe anything put on the screen.  As a nurse, do you know how many times I have heard people refer to movies and television shows regarding certain illnesses and the diagnosis and treatment of them?  You don't want to know ;)

Comment: They have no legal authority, but the WHO has [guidelines on how suicide should be portrayed](https://www.who.int/mental_health/prevention/suicide/resource_media.pdf), geared at the news. This is to try to prevent people from hearing about a suicide and attempting it themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exist no rules because movies are made for entertainment, and don't have any problem if they show a disease the way it is not. The main problem would be a complete rejection to the movie from the audience because it is showing something incorrectly. After some google research, I haven't found any case of movies being sued for this kind of thing.

Comment: +1 for the try. I am also didn't got any answer from Google yet. But i still though to wait a long to get any answer from here.

Comment: Heh i even looked for all the movies about medical conditions :) and Gajini is a great movie but i dislike the dancing.... @AnkitSharma

Comment: I only have problem with Gajini just regarding wrong portrayal of medical condition.